# How to delete less than 2 dots in regex?

Tags: python, regex

My problem is following:

I have strings where I want to delete dots less than 2 in a row. If it is more than 2 it should stay.

I try to use regex for that but it doesnt work out because it deletes everything.

The code I am using

```
re.sub('\.{,2}', '', 'Hello.... I am shy.')
```

Result I want:

```
Hello.... I am shy
```

Result I get:

```
Hello I am shy
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: To remove single dots not enclosed with other dots use `re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)', '', s)`

Comment: Can you detail your solution?

Comment: How should the regex work for strings like `Hello I'm 2.0 liters of milk`?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution

```
re.sub('(?<!\.)\.{,2}(?!\.)', '', 'Hello.... I am shy.')
```

Problem that I had to check if the match starts with dots or it follows with dots.

But we use normal regex the environment around a dot is also matched but we don't like to delete it. Therefore we use the operator

```
?<!
```

and

> ?!

which are lookbehind aand lockahead operators. You can check conditions without putting them into match. That's a great solution.

P.S.: I realised Wiktor had the same solution but he didn't give any proper explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that whatever comes after your 0, 1 or 2 dots is not a dot so you need a regex like this

```
re.sub('\.{0,2}([^.]|$)', '$1', 'Hello.... I am shy.')
```

This will look for 0, 1 or 2 dots followed by a character that is not a dot or followed by the end of the line.

**EDIT:**
Previous version stripped the character after the dots.

Comment: Do not use `{,2}`, always use the lower bound. If it is `0`, put `0` there, you will avoid many problems.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what problems do you get with `.{,2}` that you don't get with `.{0,2}`?

Comment: If you use `{,2}` in R with TRE regex, it will match up to 3 occurrences

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK but this is tagged `python` not `R`

Comment: And it is also tagged `regex`, so it is a good idea to follow best practices.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK will make the edit, I'll point out that I come from Perl where `.{,2}` is standard, which also explains my buggy Python in the first attempt of the answer. :-)

Comment: I see, that explains the other bug that is still present in your code. Also, I understand  *less than 2 in a row* as *one occurrence not enclosed with same chars*. Still waiting for OP confirmation.

Comment: I tested your version but it doesnt work on python 3.7. Result is ".."